# Retrieve facebook id from profile image address

Tags: facebook

If I only have the facebook profile address (something like https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-prn2/c0.0.180.180/1425794_10202604468931708_129792007_a.jpg ) , can I retrieve it's user ID? The aforementioned address is the only information known.

Thanks

Comment: update: found this tool: http://randomdomain.name/FacebookPictureToProfile/index.php

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

From the second set of numbers in the file name go to this URL http://facebook.com/10202604468931708

You will see that takes you to a page for that picture. On that page you can see the owner of the picture.  Navigate to the profile.

From the profile, change `www` to `graph` In the URL.

The resulting page will show the Facebook id of the user.

Answer (score 0):

The second set of numbers is indicative of the profile it originated from.

www.facebookcreep.com is a tool that takes this number and searches for the profile it came from.

Hope this helps people!